# Apply formula based on condition in certain column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like that:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([[1,0.10],[1,0.15],[3,0.16],[3,0.11],[3,0.12],[1,0.14],[2,0.17],
                  [2,0.19],[1,0.10]], columns=["a","b"])
```

result is:

```
    a   b
0   1   0.10
1   1   0.15
2   3   0.16
3   3   0.11
4   3   0.12
5   1   0.14
6   2   0.17
7   2   0.19
8   1   0.10
```

I want to create a new column "c" which value is derived from the value in column "b" but if some condition is met in column "a". Better is to see visualization of the expected result. I input the value in column "c" as string so that one better understands the expected manipulation. But in reality what I need is just a number.

```
    a     b               c
0   1   0.10    --->    (1-0.10)
1   1   0.15    --->    (1-0.15)
2   3   0.16    --->    (1-0.16)x(1-0.11)x(1-0.12)
3   3   0.11    --->    (1-0.16)x(1-0.11)x(1-0.12)
4   3   0.12    --->    (1-0.16)x(1-0.11)x(1-0.12)
5   1   0.14    --->    (1-0.14)
6   2   0.17    --->    (1-0.17)x(1-0.19)
7   2   0.19    --->    (1-0.17)x(1-0.19)
8   1   0.10    --->    (1-0.10)
```

So, if:

value in "a" is 1: then c = 1-b

if value in "a" is 2: then c = (1-b)x(1-b) for the rows where "a" is 2.

if value in "a" is 3: then c = (1-b)x(1-b)x(1-b) for the rows where "a" is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function with consecutive groups by [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and in custom function by [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) test if `a` (here `x.name[0]`) is higher like `1` and then also add  product to new column `c`:

```
def f(x):
    diff = 1-x['b']
    if x.name[0]>1:
        x['c'] = diff.prod()
    else:
        x['c'] = diff
    return x 

g = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(['a',g]).apply(f)
print (df)
   a     b         c
0  1  0.10  0.900000
1  1  0.15  0.850000
2  3  0.16  0.657888
3  3  0.11  0.657888
4  3  0.12  0.657888
5  1  0.14  0.860000
6  2  0.17  0.672300
7  2  0.19  0.672300
8  1  0.10  0.900000
```

Another idea:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].rsub(1)
g = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()
g1 = g.where(df['a'].gt(1).groupby(g).transform('all'))
df['c'] = df.groupby(g1)['c'].transform('prod').fillna(df['c'])
print (df)
   a     b         c
0  1  0.10  0.900000
1  1  0.15  0.850000
2  3  0.16  0.657888
3  3  0.11  0.657888
4  3  0.12  0.657888
5  1  0.14  0.860000
6  2  0.17  0.672300
7  2  0.19  0.672300
8  1  0.10  0.900000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do in pseudocode:

1. Add a column `diff` that is `1-b`
2. Use Pandas' `groupby` to group by `a`
3. Use Pandas' `product` to build the product over `diff` in each group and store that in column `c`